# Double relation in eloquent, no results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**TL:DR;**

City model - Locations model - Offers model.
1 city hasMany locations, locations belongToMany offers

`City::with('locations.offers')->where('slug','=', $city)->first();`

shows 0 offers from relation even though there is an offer record connected to location (which is connected to the city).

---

**Longer version:**

I have 3 models which should be connected to each other. City, Location & Offer.

I have the given city, and want to retrieve all locations with offers which are connected to the city. In the output of:

`City::with('locations.offers')->where('slug','=', $city)->first();`

I see the city and all locations connected to the city. Each location has an empty offer relation.

Model City:

```
class City extends Model
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Location');
    }
}
```

Model Location

```
class Location extends Model
{

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }

    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer','location_offer','offer_id','location_id');
    }
}
```

Model Offer

```
class Offer extends Model
{

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location','location_offer','offer_id','location_id');
    }

}
```

Database is pretty basic:

- city table holds the city information (id+title)
- location table has city_id (and location title)
- location_offer table has location_id & offer_id
- offer has offer information.

---

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but can't seem to figure it out. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect there is a small mistake in your relation

```
    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\Offers','location_offer','location_id','offer_id');
    }
```

You need to check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) the third argument is wrong

The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:

Check the Queries

This is the one that will be executed by your code

```
select `offer`.*, `location_offer`.`offer_id` as `pivot_offer_id`, `location_offer`.`location_id` as `pivot_location_id` from `offer` inner join `location_offer` on `offer`.`id` = `location_offer`.`location_id` where `location_offer`.`offer_id` in ('1', '2')
```

See join is wrong :

**join `location_offer` on `offer`.`id` = `location_offer`.`location_id`**

This is the right one

```
select `offer`.*, `location_offer`.`location_id` as `pivot_location_id`, `location_offer`.`offer_id` as `pivot_offer_id` from `offer` inner join `location_offer` on `offer`.`id` = `location_offer`.`offer_id` where `location_offer`.`location_id` in ('1', '2')
```

**join `location_offer` on `offer`.`id` = `location_offer`.`offer_id`**